# Why do I get this error when I want to connect to my database pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1105, 'direct DDL is disabled')

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql, peewee

```
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase(
  host     = "hostname",
  user     = "user",
  passwd   = "password",
  database = "db",
  ssl      = {
      "ca": "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
})
db.connect()
```

When I run this code I get this error: pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1105, 'direct DDL is disabled')

Comment: Since you are using pymysql, shouldn't the connection be done using `db = pymysql.connect()` instead of `db = MySQLDatabase()`. If not, could you explain your question with some more details?

Comment: Sounds like a database setting, ask your database administrator.